# SourceTree: how to show every individual commit log information panel?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

On one of my machines, I have somehow hidden the panel which shows commit information, such as the commit hash and the full commit message. Here is the appearance with the commit panel
I'm sure it's just a setting somewhere to bring the commit panel back, but I can't find it. Can anyone help me out?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On the bottom of your SourceTree window, make sure you're not on the search tab or the File Status tab; it has to be

> Log/History

tab for it to show the version history